# jquery select trigger action if option is changed from specific value to another specific value

Tags: jquery, html, select, html-select

In this code. I have the 'No path' option value trigger something when it is selected.
I have a hierachy of No Path, Mono, Stereo, Surround.  Surround being the highest option and no path being the lowest.

What I'm trying to do is only have that the div class triggered if the option was higher eg. Surround.

So if the option is on "surround" and I change to "Stereo" then it will trigger the event.

The same applies if I went from "Surround" to "Mono" that would also trigger an event because I am going from higher to lower.

However...If I were to go from "Mono" to "Stereo"  (or "Mono" to "Surround) this would not trigger the event because it is going to a higher option.

I have tried to do this manually but the code got confusing and very long and just didnt work.

It is almost like

if - changing to an option that is less important (or lower than) the option that was previously selected - Trigger Event

else - Don't trigger Event.

I've trawled through lots of sites and tried to piece this together but only get about halfway before I am stuck.

Any thoughts on how to do this better?

Here is the code:

Script

```
var hello = ('select option:selected');
alert(hello);

$('select').on('change', function () {
    var valueSelected = this.value;

    alert(valueSelected);
    if($(this).val() === 'No Path'){
         $('.do-something').addClass('triggered');   
  }
});
```

HTML

```
  <select class="bus-width btn-light-outline">
    <option value="No Path">No Path</option>
    <option value="Mono">Mono</option>
    <option value="Stereo">Stereo</option>
    <option value="Surround">5.1 Surround</option>
  </select>

<div class="do-something">This needs to be triggered</div>
```

CSS

```
.do-something {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:70px;
    padding:30px;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.triggered {
  background:green;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/dh5ma2j1/

Comment: What about adding a numerical data attribute to the options and just checking if the value of that is higher or lower than the previously selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Basically the index is the position of the element as it is presented in the document, so the first option would have index=0, second option would have index=1, and so on. We get the current selected option's index, and compare it to that of the last selected.

```
var lastIndex = null;

$('select').on('change', function () {

    var thisIndex = $(this).find(":selected").index();

    if(thisIndex < lastIndex){
        $('.do-something').addClass('triggered');   
    } else {
        $('.do-something').removeClass('triggered');   
    }

    lastIndex = thisIndex;

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/dh5ma2j1/5/

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Rank the selections and compare ranks.

```
var ranking = ['No Path', 'Mono', 'Stereo', 'Surround']
var current_rank = 0

$('select').on('change', function () {

    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if(ranking.indexOf(valueSelected) < current_rank){
         $('.do-something').addClass('triggered'); 
    } else {
         $('.do-something').removeClass('triggered');    
    }
    current_rank = ranking.indexOf(valueSelected)
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh5ma2j1/3/)

Comment: This works perfectly also. If I could choose both answers I would but the other option just suited my use case ever so slightly more. Thanks :)